# Generate self-signed SSL certificate using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, ssl-certificate

Is it possible for a Qt program to generate a self-signed SSL certificate and private key, i.e. the `cacert.pem` and `privkey.pem` files, using only Qt functions?

The program would be running on a Symbian phone (it's an FTPS server), so openssl command-line tools would not be available.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do that without openssl.

Comment: I wouldn't create them on the fly (as QT can't). Create them before deploying (eg http://tinyca.sm-zone.net/ ) the software and hope no one tries to break them ;-)

Comment: Yes, I could probably add a hard-coded certificate, load it from a QByteArray, or add the pem files as resources.

Comment: There are no classes to do generation of certificates with Qt at this point.  They are actually just being discussed now on the Qt5 developers mailing lists as something to be added, but they certainly don't exist now.

Comment: OK, in that case this answers my question. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apperently there are some Qt classes that do this, starting from Qt version 5.14:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopcuax509certificatesigningrequest.html#createSelfSignedCertificate

Answer (score 3):

I've written an addon to Qt that will allow you to do this with a nice Qt-style API. It can be obtained here https://gitorious.org/qt-certificate-addon/ and the docs are online at http://xmelegance.org/devel/qt-certificate-addon/ it includes a couple of examples that should get you started.

Comment: Your project has dependencies on GnuTLS, though, and I can't use it because of that. This is because I need to compile everything using Qt Creator's ARM toolchain for Nokia phones, and it can't compile GNU autotools projects.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are no classes that do this in Qt, so it is impossible to do with only Qt functions currently.